# Can a non-premium account and a premium account play on the same copy of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've got an alt. account for my copy of Minecraft, but it is non-premium since I didn't buy a copy for the account. I've already got a copy of Minecraft for my already-premium account, so is there a way I can play my alt. on my premium account's game, or do I have to buy an entirely new copy of Minecraft for that account?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can play both accounts on the same copy of Minecraft.

Open your launcher, in the top right it will show your user name.  Click it and it will give you the option to switch accounts.
[image: Corner]

From there click 'Add a new user' and input your alternate account information.
[image: New User]

From then on you will be able to switch between accounts.  You can have several accounts if you like.

---

Edit:  I reread your question and you use the term alt which made me think of multiplayer.  Demo mode accounts can not play multiplayer.